# Change the name of many files

Tags: regex, unix, terminal

How can I rename many files. Remove the digits at the beginning.
I have a Mac. All the files are in the same folder.

The pattern is:
1, 2 or 3 digits - any name.php
With Regular Expression, I think it would be:
\d*-(.*).php

For example:
1-marketing.php
2-3D.php
3-without.php

I want to remove the numbers and the dash at the beginning.

In the example it would be:
marketing.php
3D.php
without.php

What I have explored two ways:
Select the files > ctrl click > rename items. This is a fantastic method to change the name of files. But I think it cannot be used in this case. If I understand, it does not support Regex. Am I right?

Terminal. I am not very familiar with terminal. I tried mv 1-marketing.php marketing.php It works for 1 file, but how can I do the same for many? I am new with the terminal. If it can be done, please explain the basic.

Comment: Are you in a Windows or a Linux machine?

Comment: There's the `rename` command (actually, there are two commands with that name, but they do more or less the same thing).

Comment: @Inian: I am in a Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `terminal` app in `Mac OS X` and navigate to the folder containing the `.php` files

```
cd /my/path/to-php-files/
```

and run the below command on the command-line.

```
for file in *.php; do mv -v "$file" "${file#*-}"; done
```

The `bash` parameter expansion syntax `${file#*-}` removes the characters before `-` from the beginning, so ideally `3-number-without.php` becomes `number-without.php`

(or) use the `perl rename` utility not available by default in `Mac OS`, you can download and install it with [homebrew](http://brew.sh) :

```
brew install rename
```

and do

```
rename -n 's/^(\d+)-(.*)/$2/' *.php
```

The `-n` is just for a dry-run to see how the files are to be renamed, remove it as

```
rename 's/^(\d+)-(.*)/$2/' *.php
```

for the actual renaming.

Comment: What is -v?, Do you know where a beginner can learn the basics about writing that kind of code?

Comment: @Nrc: `-v` is for verbose operation, it enables printing in `stdout` information as `3-marketing.php -> marketing.php`

Comment: @Nrc: It is a good practice to start with some basics, something like [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/bash.htm)

Comment: I put simplified files name examples. Real names are more complex, for example: 3-without-brand.php and it changes to brand.php. Remember, the pattern is to remove the digits and the dash (only the dash after the numbers)

Comment: @Nrc: Refer my first example in `bash` for the update. I tested it on mine, try it on your own before actual renaming.

Comment: @Nrc: Refer my update for both the examples, it should solve the problem now

Comment: @Nrc; refer my update again. It removes the characters until the first occurrence of `-` in string

Comment: @Nrc: Happy you found it useful.