# How to install rename in a Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I have been searching how to install rename to change file names with the terminal and mac. In several places explain that I should put

```
brew install rename
```

[Change the name of many files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778845/change-the-name-of-many-files/41778911#41778911)

If I write that in the terminal it says

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment:  http://brew.sh

Comment: You are missing brew? http://brew.sh/

Comment: For future reference, always remember to Google the error message you're getting first. Very often, you will find a solution to your problem right among the first couple results.

Comment: Why the negative points. Why am I supposed to know and understand that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting indicates that you need to install Homebrew.  Start with this [page](http://brew.sh/).  Once Homebrew is installed, you can install additional utilities through it.